# Replacing an obsolete battery

Tags: battery, compaq-laptop

I have a HP Compaq NX6610 laptop with a dead battery. Now, HP have stopped making battery for this model. I am in confusion on how I can replace my battery with the battery of any other model of HP.

Is it possible?

Comment: No, unless the other model of the laptop uses the same model of the battery.

Comment: Have you checked ebay?

Comment: Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: You're are at your risk (Chances of this working is about `90%`)

Yes it is possible, but you will have to be a little be technical and messy on it.

Remove your laptop battery and take it along with you to any store that sell replacement batteries for laptops, check for a replacement battery for HP Compaq `nx6110` it should be the same with your hp compaq `nx6610`, you're lucky then, you can buy a replacement battery for `nx6110` and use it for your `NX6610`.

Else, check the size of your battery, if it's the same size with that of hp compaq `nx6110`, this is where the thing get a bit messy. Buy the battery, a sharp knife, and a good glue.

Ensure the size of the battery is the same, use the sharp knife to open the new replacement battery you bought (hp compaq `nx6110`), that is, you will have to remove the cells from the black plastic that houses the cells. Repeat the same thing to your dead battery, but you will have to be very careful in opening it (**because you will still use it again**), after you've successfully open your dead battery, disconnect all the wired connection from the cells and remove the cells of your old battery and also disconnect all the wired connection from the cells of new replacement battery, then replace the cells of your old dead battery of with the new cells you've removed from the new replacement battery you got, then you ensure that all your wired connections of the cells you just transferred to the old case of your dead battery are connected properly.

**Ensure you fix your wired connections properly**

Carefully close the case of your old battery, which should now house the new cells, then you can use the glue to glue the edges of the parts you use the knife to open. Keep the battery for some minutes depending on the type of glue your got, to dry adequately.

Then you're good to go! you should now have a self made new replacement battery.

**If the procedure is kinda technical for you, feel free to meet a technician to help you out with the procedure**

Comment: please stop editing posts *only* to add codeblocks formatting to model names and other superfluous parts. Codeblocks are for complete commands and blocks of text such as code or error messages. Likewise models do not need to be in bold or italics. The formatting is meant to be used for clarity and emphasis, not just because it is a model number.

Comment: @Mokubai okay..